# Spinner : setOnItemSelected when Visibility is GONE

Tags: android, spinner, listener

Do you have any tricks to set a listener on a spinner when its visibility is View.GONE ?
When I add the listener without specifying View.GONE it works fine but then if I add

```
spinner.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

the listener no longer works.

Any ideas?

Comment: try spinner.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: GONE and still wants to set listener? Instead try INVISIBLE

Comment: this will hide the spinner but itll still take the room as if it was still there .. And thats not what i want :)

Comment: What i can try is INVISIBLE and set a width to zero, ill try and ill get back to you !

Answer (score -1):

GONE - The view is invisible and gone.

INVISIBLE -  The view is just invisible.

Try with View.INVISIBLE.